# xmlParse throws Cannot find the declaration of element after providing namespace

Tags: xml, coldfusion, lucee

I got a schema like the following from a customer. I shortened it and changed some names.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://mysite.local/bo" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="UUID">
            <xs:simpleType>
                   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:pattern
                            value="[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{4}-[A-Fa-f0-9]{12}">
                      </xs:pattern>
                   </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element type="xs:date" name="DOB"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I built the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://mysite.local/bo">
    <UUID>0000f34b-0a01-9604-3400-270461ed42b2</UUID>
    <DOB>2019-05-14</DOB>
</Data>
```

In ColdFusion I call `<cfset xmlParse( xml, true, fileRead(expandPath("./schema.xsd"), "utf-8"))>` and an exception is thrown with the message: `cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Data'.` Adobe ColdFusion and Lucee agree on that error.
I had addded the `xmlns` attribut to the `Data` element. I send this xml to a system of a customer and it is accepted and successfully processed. I wonder why ColdFusion throws the exception. I guess it has to do with namespaces.

Comment: Any particular version of ColdFusion?

Comment: I don't know ColdFusion but the XSD/XML combination looks valid to me so it's either a limitation of the tools you are using, or you are invoking the validation process incorrectly.

Comment: I tried ACF 11 and Lucee 5

Comment: FWIW, same behavior in CF2016.